# Get uniq random lines from file and write them to another file using php

Tags: php, random, lines

I have file consists of 10000 different lines. I need to take 100 random uniq lines from this file and write them to another file. What is the easiest way to do it using php?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

A *naive* way:

```
$lines = file('somefile.txt');
shuffle($lines);
$random_lines = array_slice($lines, 0, 10);
```

**Note:** This completely disregards system resource considerations.

Comment: + I like the `This completely disregards system resource considerations.` part ...

Comment: I know. **Don't try this at home kids!**

Answer (score 3):

A faster solution larger lines

```
function m1($file) {
    $fp = fopen($file, "r");
    $size = filesize($file);
    $list = array();
    $n = 0;
    while ( true ) {
        fseek($fp, mt_rand(0, $size));
        fgets($fp);
        $pos = ftell($fp);
        isset($list[$pos]) or $s = trim(fgets($fp)) and $list[$pos] = $s and $n ++;
        if ($n >= 100)
            break;
    }
    return $list;
}



function m2($file) {
    $lines = file($file);
    shuffle($lines);
    $list = array_slice($lines, 0, 100);
    return $list;
}
```

Simple Benchmark with Accepted Solution

10,000 Lines

```
Array
(
    [m1] => 0.013591051101685 <------ M1 Faster
    [m2] => 0.033689975738525
)
```

100,000 Line

```
Array
(
    [m1] => 0.014040946960449 <------ M1 Faster
    [m2] => 0.094476938247681
)
```

[Full Benchmark Code](http://pastebin.com/TJK5urCb)

[File Used](http://bayfiles.com/file/s4M5/b52m3O/log.txt)

Comment: Thanks  ... only responded because you said `A naive way:` in case case other people wanted alternative for larger files

Comment: Agreed. Your solution is they way to go.

Comment: @Jason McCreary not really .. how many people deal with 1,000,000 lines of files .... for the majority your solution is the way to go