# SplFileObject move pointer to previous line

Tags: php, logging, iteration, text-files

So I am doing a small experiment for myself, a script to read the php errors' log file (with SplFileObject) and output it formatted on the browser.

I though it would be more logic to display it in reversed order (the latest errors on top).
To use the "normal" order I would just display each line and call $file->next(); to move the pointer, but as I'm doing it the other way around, and there's not a `prev()` or `previous()` method as far as I know, the only way I found was using `seek()`:

```
for($i = $lines_total - $start_at; $i > $lines_total - $start_at - $lines_to_get; $i--){
    $content->seek($i);
    $data = $content->current();
    if(empty($data)){
        continue;
    }
}
```

But this is incredibly slow (around 7 Secs for a 16mb file). If I do it in the normal order it's instant.

Do anyone knows any method? or what I'm trying to do is crazy? xD I'm just a designer forced to code, so I am not very familiarized with pointers and stuff like that.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In case anybody encounters this problem in the future I came up with a quite simple solution:

```
//get to the last position of the file and get the pointer position.
$content->seek($content->getSize());
$lines_total = $content->key();
$byte = $content->ftell();

//all the line in the php error log starts like: [21-Feb-2013 22:34:53 UTC] so...
$pattern = '/^\[.*\]/';

for(...){
//get the current output to preg_match it
    $data = $content->current();

//go backward each time it doesnt match a line's start
    while ( preg_match( $pattern, $data ) === 0 ){
    $byte--;
    $content->fseek($byte);
    $data = $content->current();
    }

//go backward 1 more position to start the next loop
    $byte--;
    $content->fseek($byte);
}
```

Hope this helps someone someday xD

Answer (score 2):

FROM PHP DOC

> [prev](http://php.net/manual/en/function.prev.php) — Rewind the internal array pointer 
>   [prev()](http://php.net/manual/en/function.prev.php) behaves just like [next()](http://php.net/manual/en/function.next.php), except it rewinds the internal array pointer one place instead of advancing it.

As you can see they only work with arrays not file pointer .... you can only use it like this

```
$file = new SplFileObject("log.txt", "r");
$file  = iterator_to_array($file);

echo current($file), PHP_EOL;
echo next($file), PHP_EOL;
echo prev($file), PHP_EOL;
```

If you want to move to the next line you can try using `SplFileObject::ftell` to get the previous position then use `SplFileObject::fseek` to implement your reverse ...

Example

```
$file = new ReverseableSplFileObject("log.txt", "r");
foreach ( $file as $c ) {
    echo $c, PHP_EOL;
}
echo $file->prev(), PHP_EOL;
echo $file->prev(), PHP_EOL;
echo $file->prev(), PHP_EOL;
```

Output

```
A
B
C
C
B
A
```

Modified class

```
class ReverseableSplFileObject extends SplFileObject {
    private $pos = array();

    function current() {
        return trim(parent::current());
    }

    function next() {
        $this->eof() or $this->pos[] = $this->ftell();
        return parent::next();
    }

    function prev() {
        if (empty($this->pos)) {
            $this->fseek(0);
        } else {
            $this->fseek(array_pop($this->pos));
        }
        return $this->current();
    }
}
```

Comment: Thank you, although i've been researching a  bit and people told me that doing it with arrays wouldn't be good with performance. I figured it out a way using fseek. Thank you for your help anyway! :D

Comment: For performance `fseek` is faster than iterator .. see http://stackoverflow.com/a/13421745/1226894

Answer (score 0):

This is an old question but with SplFileObj the simplest way is to use the key and seek,

```
public function prev(){
    $key = $this->_splFileObj->key();
    if( $key ){
        --$key;
    }
    $this->_splFileObj->seek($key);
}
```

Assuming this method is in a wrapper around SplFileObj with the property of `_splFileObj`.